# FFmpeg filtergraph memory leak

Tags: c, video, memory, ffmpeg, racket

I have an FFmpeg program that:

1. Demuxes and decodes a video file.
2. Passes it through a filtergraph
3. encodes and muxes the new video.

The filtergraph itself is rather complex, and can be run directly from the command line as such:

```
ffmpeg -i demo.mp4 -filter_complex \
 "[audio3]atrim=end=30:start=10[audio2];\
  [video5]trim=end=30:start=10[video4];[audio2]anull[audio6];\
  [video4]scale=width=1920:height=1080[video7];[audio6]anull[audio8];\
  [video7]fps=fps=30[video9];[audio8]anull[audio10];\
  [video9]format=pix_fmts=yuv420p[video11];\
  [audio10]asetpts=expr=PTS-STARTPTS[audio12];\
  [video11]setpts=expr=PTS-STARTPTS[video13];\
  [audio15]concat=v=0:a=1:n=1[audio14];\
  [video17]concat=v=1:a=0:n=1[video16];\
  [audio12]afifo[audio15];[video13]fifo[video17];\
  [audio14]afifo[audio18];[video16]fifo[video19];\
  [audio18]anull[audio20];\
  [video19]pad=width=1920:height=1080[video21];\
  [audio20]anull[audio22];[video21]fps=fps=25[video23];\
  [audio22]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo[fa];\
  [video23]format=pix_fmts=yuv420p[fv];[0:a]afifo[audio3];\
  [0:v]fifo[video5]" \
-map "[fv]" -map "[fa]" out.mp4
```

I realize this is a massive filtergraph with a lot of no-op filters, it was autogenerated rather than being hand written. [Here is a more cleaner version of the graph.](https://gist.github.com/LeifAndersen/68c87563c8f2f7af3ea7913b65c651b6) (Its a graphviz file, you can run it in the command line or [here](http://webgraphviz.com/).)

Anyway, when I run the program that uses this filtergraph my memory usage spikes. I end up using about 7 GB of RAM for a 30 second clip. However, when I run the program using the ffmpeg command above, it peaks out at about 600 MB of RAM. This causes me to believe that the problem is not the ungodly size of the filtergraph, but a problem with how my program is using it.

The program sets up the filtergraph (using `av_filter_parse_ptr`, giving the filtergraph string shown above), encoder, muxer, decoder, and demuxer, then spawns two threads, one that sends frames into the filtergraph, and one that receives them. The frame that sends them looks something like:

```
void decode () {
    while(... more_frames ...) {
        AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();
        ... fill next frame of stream ...
        av_buffersrc_write_frame(ctx, frame);
        av_frame_free(&frame);
    }
}
```

(I have elided the `av_send_packet/av_receive_frame` functions as they don't seem to be leaking memory. I have also elided the process of flushing the buffersrc as that won't happen until the end, and the memory spikes long before that.)

And the encoder thread looks similar:

```
void encode() {
    while(... nodes_in_graph ...) {
        AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();
        av_buffersink_get_frame(ctx, frame);
        ... ensure frame actually was filled ...
        ... send frame to encoder ...
        av_frame_free(&frame);
    }
}
```

As with the decoder, I have elided the `send_frame/receive_packet` combo as they don't seem to be leaking memory. Additionally I have elided the details of ensuring that the frame actually was filled. The code loops until the frame eventually does get filled.

Every frame I allocate I fairly quickly deallocate. I additionally handled all of the error cases that the ffmpeg can give (Elided in the example).

I have also tried having only one frame for the encoder and one for the decoder (and calling `av_frame_unref` in each iteration of the loop).

Am I forgetting to free something, or am I just using the calls to libavfilter incorrectly such that it has to buffer all of the data? I don't think the leak is caused by the memory graph because running it from the command line doesn't seem to cause the same memory explosion.

FWIW, the actual code is [here](https://github.com/videolang/video/blob/master/video/private/ffmpeg-pipeline.rkt), although its written in Racket. I do have a minimal example that also seems to duplicate this behavior (modified from the `doc/example/filtering_video.c` file from the ffmpeg code:

```
#include <unistd.h>

#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavfilter/avfiltergraph.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersink.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersrc.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>

const char *filter_descr = "trim=start=10:end=30,scale=78:24,transpose=cclock";

static AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx;
static AVCodecContext *dec_ctx;
AVFilterContext *buffersink_ctx;
AVFilterContext *buffersrc_ctx;
AVFilterGraph *filter_graph;
static int video_stream_index = -1;
static int64_t last_pts = AV_NOPTS_VALUE;

static int open_input_file(const char *filename)
{
    int ret;
    AVCodec *dec;

    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&fmt_ctx, filename, NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot open input file\n");
        return ret;
    }

    if ((ret = avformat_find_stream_info(fmt_ctx, NULL)) < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot find stream information\n");
        return ret;
    }

    /* select the video stream */
    ret = av_find_best_stream(fmt_ctx, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, -1, -1, &dec, 0);
    if (ret < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot find a video stream in the input file\n");
        return ret;
    }
    video_stream_index = ret;

    /* create decoding context */
    dec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(dec);
    if (!dec_ctx)
        return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
    avcodec_parameters_to_context(dec_ctx, fmt_ctx->streams[video_stream_index]->codecpar);
    av_opt_set_int(dec_ctx, "refcounted_frames", 1, 0);

    /* init the video decoder */
    if ((ret = avcodec_open2(dec_ctx, dec, NULL)) < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot open video decoder\n");
        return ret;
    }

    return 0;
}

static int init_filters(const char *filters_descr)
{
    char args[512];
    int ret = 0;
    AVFilter *buffersrc  = avfilter_get_by_name("buffer");
    AVFilter *buffersink = avfilter_get_by_name("buffersink");
    AVFilterInOut *outputs = avfilter_inout_alloc();
    AVFilterInOut *inputs  = avfilter_inout_alloc();
    AVRational time_base = fmt_ctx->streams[video_stream_index]->time_base;
    enum AVPixelFormat pix_fmts[] = { AV_PIX_FMT_GRAY8, AV_PIX_FMT_NONE };

    filter_graph = avfilter_graph_alloc();
    if (!outputs || !inputs || !filter_graph) {
        ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
        goto end;
    }

    /* buffer video source: the decoded frames from the decoder will be inserted here. */
    snprintf(args, sizeof(args),
            "video_size=%dx%d:pix_fmt=%d:time_base=%d/%d:pixel_aspect=%d/%d",
            dec_ctx->width, dec_ctx->height, dec_ctx->pix_fmt,
            time_base.num, time_base.den,
            dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.num, dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.den);

    ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersrc_ctx, buffersrc, "in",
                                   args, NULL, filter_graph);
    if (ret < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot create buffer source\n");
        goto end;
    }

    /* buffer video sink: to terminate the filter chain. */
    ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersink_ctx, buffersink, "out",
                                       NULL, NULL, filter_graph);
    if (ret < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot create buffer sink\n");
        goto end;
    }

    ret = av_opt_set_int_list(buffersink_ctx, "pix_fmts", pix_fmts,
                              AV_PIX_FMT_NONE, AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
    if (ret < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot set output pixel format\n");
        goto end;
    }

    outputs->name       = av_strdup("in");
    outputs->filter_ctx = buffersrc_ctx;
    outputs->pad_idx    = 0;
    outputs->next       = NULL;
    inputs->name       = av_strdup("out");
    inputs->filter_ctx = buffersink_ctx;
    inputs->pad_idx    = 0;
    inputs->next       = NULL;

    if ((ret = avfilter_graph_parse_ptr(filter_graph, filters_descr,
                                    &inputs, &outputs, NULL)) < 0)
        goto end;

    if ((ret = avfilter_graph_config(filter_graph, NULL)) < 0)
        goto end;

end:
    avfilter_inout_free(&inputs);
    avfilter_inout_free(&outputs);

    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ret;
    AVPacket packet;
    AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();
    AVFrame *filt_frame = av_frame_alloc();

    if (!frame || !filt_frame) {
        perror("Could not allocate frame");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    av_register_all();
    avfilter_register_all();

    if ((ret = open_input_file(argv[1])) < 0)
        goto end;
    if ((ret = init_filters(filter_descr)) < 0)
        goto end;

    /* read all packets */
    while (1) {
        if ((ret = av_read_frame(fmt_ctx, &packet)) < 0)
            break;

        if (packet.stream_index == video_stream_index) {
            ret = avcodec_send_packet(dec_ctx, &packet);
            if (ret < 0) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Error while sending a packet to the decoder\n");
                break;
            }

            while (ret >= 0) {
                ret = avcodec_receive_frame(dec_ctx, frame);
                if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
                    break;
                } else if (ret < 0) {
                    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Error while receiving a frame from the decoder\n");
                    goto end;
                }

                if (ret >= 0) {
                     frame->pts = av_frame_get_best_effort_timestamp(frame);

                    /* push the decoded frame into the filtergraph */
                    if (av_buffersrc_add_frame_flags(buffersrc_ctx, frame, AV_BUFFERSRC_FLAG_KEEP_REF) < 0) {
                        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Error while feeding the filtergraph\n");
                        break;
                    }

                    /* pull filtered frames from the filtergraph */
                    while (1) {
                        ret = av_buffersink_get_frame(buffersink_ctx, filt_frame);
                        if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
                            break;
                        if (ret < 0)
                            goto end;
                        av_frame_unref(filt_frame);
                    }
                    av_frame_unref(frame);
                }
            }
        }
        av_packet_unref(&packet);
    }
end:
    avfilter_graph_free(&filter_graph);
    avcodec_free_context(&dec_ctx);
    avformat_close_input(&fmt_ctx);
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    av_frame_free(&filt_frame);

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: If the code is in racket, why do you post incomplete snippets of C code?

Comment: Because the FFmpeg libraries are written in C, and I'm using a C FFI to bind to them. As well as using the C style memory management.

Comment: Perhaps to specific for SO, I'd head over to the ffmpeg-mailinglists instead, but then again, you'll never know...

Comment: Mm...good point. Well I'll do that and come back with whatever answer I find.

Comment: @LeifAndersen did you ever fix this problem? I believe I am experiencing the same thing. DrMemory reports a *possible leak*, which is upgraded to a leak when I try freeing the `buffersrc`/`buffersink` `AVFilter*` pointers in `init_filters()`. Running the function more frequently doesn't seem to make it worse, and I have looked through the FFmpeg source and it seems the functions don't allocate any memory, just set a pointer.